# How to use key in Type two times

Tags: typescript, union-types

Is it possible to use `key in Type` two times in a type?

For example:

```
type UnionTypeOne = '1' | '2'
type UnionTypeTwo = '3' | '4'

export type MyTime = {
  [key in UnionTypeOne]?: {
    [name: string]: boolean
  }
  [key in UnionTypeTwo]: boolean
}
```

Right now the compilation fails because the second (`[key in UnionTypeTwo]: boolean`) is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Use intersection types:

```
export type MyTime = {
  [key in UnionTypeOne]?: {
    [name: string]: boolean
  }
} & {
  [key in UnionTypeTwo]: boolean
};
```

Comment: Why is that needed?

Comment: @DDDDDD: Probably because allowing two index signatures would get strange if there are conflicting names (whereas intersection types already handle that).